# How to change datatype of all the columns in datatable in c#

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, c#-datatable

I have a DataTable dt whose all columns are of type string but many of them have "interger values" in them but as a string only.

For Example:-

ColA

23

34

56

These are also stored in datatable but as a string value.

I want to know how can I make a clone of my datatable with columns having valid datatype according to the content of that column.

Comment: Hi, i ave seen that but there they have done it with only int32, where as i am asking to first get the type and then convert accordingly.

Comment: @PranayDeep get type from what?

Comment: You probably need to test each string if they can be converted into other data type, and then creates a table according to the test result

Comment: How is the datatable populated?  Can you do the conversion there rather than populating _then_ converting?

Comment: it is populating from an xml.

Answer (score 0):

In this case you can use the `typeof` to enumerate through a list of types and determine what type it is.
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/58918ffs.aspx

For example you can do something like that:

```
if (obj1.GetType() == typeof(int)){
    // do something with int
}else if (obj1.GetType() == typeof(string)){
    // do something with string
}
```

Otherwise if it isn't an object but just a value you can compare with `is`:

```
if (myValue is Foo)
    Foo foo = (Foo)myValue;
```

**EDIT:**
Ok I did a mistake. You have to use `tryParse` to achieve what you want. The approach is pretty the same, you have to loop through different types and check the return value if the parsing was successful. For example:

```
int number;

bool result = Int32.TryParse(myString, out number);
if (result)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Converted '{0}' to {1}.", myString, number);         
}
```

Comment: Oh I see... didn't understand that, sorry. Well there is still a similar solution with the `tryParse`. I'll edit my answer above.